# mouse listener in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a program in Haskell using opengl that draws a circle when the mouse is clicked, where it is clicked. The trouble is, I can't find anything that can show me how to make a mouse listener. Does anybody know any good tutorial sites?

Comment: Have a look at [gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss).  I think it provides a "mouse listener."

Comment: Be sure use install gloss using the GLFW-b backend (-f GLFW)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using GLUT, you'll find what you need in `Graphics.UI.GLUT.Callbacks.Window`, specifically, `keyboardMouseCallback`.  Note that mouse buttons are treated like keyboard keys:

```
myKeyboardMouseCallback key keyState modifiers position =
  case (key, keyState) of
    (MouseButton LeftButton, Down) -> do
      {- draw circle @ position ... -}
    _ -> return () -- ignore other buttons

attachMyKeyboardMouseCallback = keyboardMouseCallback $= Just myKeyboardMouseCallback
```

Comment: thanks! Im looking at the documentation and it doesn't look like it has a `get x` or `get y` method. Would you have any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: The position (in window relative coordinates) is passed to the callback whenever a key/button is pressed (the `position` argument).  It has one constructor `Position x y`.  Simply pattern match to extract them.

Comment: i.e. `myKeyboardMouseCallback key keyState modifiers (Position x y) =
...`

Comment: I keep getting an error that doesn't like the attach part. it says the maybe type of myKeyboardMouseCallback can't be matched with its actual type. Is something wrong?

Comment: Oops, the handler is a `Maybe`, which allows you to use `Nothing` to indicate no handler.  The callback needs to be wrapped in a `Just`.  I'll update the example